# Data snapshot fails casting

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im currently using firebase to store all my information, i did a user registration using the firebase authentication and extended that user to the database reusing the id created in the authentication, now i need to get all users and compare his phones with a phone inserted with the user and retrive that specific user if the number match so i did this:

**Code**

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Users")
                .addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                        for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                            Log.d("snapshot", String.valueOf(snapshot));
                            Log.d("snap",String.valueOf(snapshot.getValue(User.class)));
                            User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);
                            if(number.equals(String.valueOf(user.getPhone()))){
                                userFriend = user;
                            }

                        }

                        if(userFriend == null){
                            //to do snackbar
                        }
                    }
```

**User class**

```
public class User {

    private String id;
    private String username;
    private int age = -1;
    private String phone;
    private int gamesPlayed = 0;
    private ArrayList<User> friends = new ArrayList<User>();

    // CONSTRUCTOR
    public User() {

    }

    public User(String username) {
        this.username = username;
    }

    // GETTERS & SETTERS
    public String getUsername() { return username; }
    public void setUsername(String username) { this.username = username; }

    public User(String id, String username, int age, String phone, int gamesPlayed, ArrayList<User> users) {
        this.id = id;
        this.username = username;
        this.age = age;
        this.phone = phone;
        this.gamesPlayed = gamesPlayed;
        this.friends = users;
    }

    public int getAge() { return age; }
    public void setAge(int age) { this.age = age; }
```

My DB structure:

[image: 1]

**And here is what i get on the stacktrace:**

```
04-20 16:06:04.070 30972-30972/com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                               Process: com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager, PID: 30972
   com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Failed to convert value of type java.lang.Long to String
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzaF(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.zze(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg$zza.zzaH(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zze(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zzb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtg.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(Unknown Source)
       at com.esmad.pdm.friendlymanager.Friends$1.onDataChange(Friends.java:61)
       at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main
```

(ZygoteInit.java:776)

the error is related to this line: `User user = snapshot.getValue(User.class);`

I suspect that it has something to do to the way I construct my User model and the data that I retrieve, something is not compatible. I have 2 int at my model gamesPlayed and age, but when i pass the user to the snapshot i don't know how to cas 2 specific values so i can pass them do i need to redifine the user instance? or is everything fine, please help me im confused :/`

Answer (score 0):

In your User class your phone field must be of type Long.

Comment: why it can't be of type string?

Comment: Bacause you're not storing it as a string in your database, if you want to retrieve it as a string put the phone numbers between quotation marks in your db, like "91351246".  I strongly recommend you save them as strings so you can later format them